# Aspose PDF .Net repeating same image multiple times in a table

Tags: pdf-generation, aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm trying to add a table to a PDF. Each row will have an image in a column. There are 3 images which will repeat in the rows.

If I just directly add the image to table cell like below, performance is very poor. It may be cause each image is treated as a separate new one.

```
cell.Paragraphs.Add(new Image(imagePath + "on.png"));
```

The below article describes how to add images to resources and reuse it. But I'm not able to figure out how this should be applied to a table cell. To be precise I'm able to add Aspose.Pdf.Image to a cell but not Aspose.Pdf.XImage.

https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Manipulate+Images#ManipulateImages-AddImagetoExistingPDFFile

Comment: We have logged an investigation ticket with ID PDFNET-46900 in our issue management system and will let you know our findings about your scenario. PS: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reuse the same Image object.

```
Image img = new Image(imagePath + "on.png");
cell.Paragraphs.Add(img):
cell.Paragraphs.Add(img):
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, the file size it close to 10 MB for 1000 rows if we do this way. Also it takes more time when saving the file. The link in the question addresses this problem but it is not clear on how to apply this for table with in a pdf.

Comment: Try contacting Aspose support, they should have a solution for you. Then you can also post it here as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai! I've already raised it [here](https://forum.aspose.com/t/using-single-image-multiple-times-in-a-table-in-pdf-document/200798). Will update here if I get any solution.